# angular: routing isn't showing my component properly

Tags: angular

My **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login/login.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My **app-routing.module**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login/login.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {
      path: 'ok',
      component: LoginComponent,
  },
  // otherwise redirect to home
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: LoginComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
  exports:[
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I want to show my login component as a home page, and whatever path I pick will also redirect to my login component.  I tried putting my `logincomponent` in bootstrap in my app.module.ts but it gave me an error.

My login component is a simple `<p>login works!</p>`

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The error when I try putting logincomponent as my bootstrap is: The selector "app-login" did not match any elements

Comment: what is the requirement

Comment: I want to be able to show my logincomponent as my home page and whatever other path goes to that component as well.  For example localhost:4000 ->login component, localhost:4000/qpownqwo ->logincomponent, etc.

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the routes as follows,

```
 imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: LoginViewComponent },
      { path: 'ok', component: LoginViewComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
    ])
  ]
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-txicx9)**

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Routes`  add a `redirect` route and `pathMatch` property to tell the router how to match a URL to the path of a route

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
     { path: '',   redirectTo: '/ok', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
          path: 'ok',
          component: LoginComponent,
      },
      // otherwise redirect to home
      { 
        path: '**', 
        component: LoginComponent 
      }
    ];
```